# In Death on the Nile, why did these characters think their plan would work?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-on-the-nile, death-on-the-nile-2022

In *Death on the Nile*, as part of their plan to kill Linnet, they needed Simon to run across the ship in the middle of the night to get to the bedroom where Linnet was sleeping.

This would have entailed a lot of risk for Simon, as he could have been seen by someone who was still awake at those late hours, which would have raised suspicion on its own, but because his alibi depended on him being shot in the leg, being seen running after the time his leg was (supposedly!) shot would have spelled his demise.

Comment: Fact is, it did work! Except for Poirot that is.

Comment: Your question is probably attracting downvotes and closevotes because its merely stating that you have a personal opinion that the plan is not very good and that you can see risks and holes in it.  Clearly (since they did it), the characters considered the plan "good enough" - but they don't *have* to have a plan which is good enough for you, just good enough for themselves.  As long as its not totally inconceivable that (given the circumstances) it was a risk worth taking then the plan doesn't need to be something convincing to you.

Comment: It’s important to remember that in the story, after simon and jackie found that the maid louise saw simon and threatened to blackmail them, they decided to kill her off on the ship! Clearly, these people were terrified at the idea that they might be noticed that night.  So you tell me, does it sound like they thought the risk was worth taking, or perhaps you’re suggesting they were too careless to have foresaw that happening? Yet they must have gone over every other step of their plan exhaustively.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all whodunnit resolutions hinge on a perfectly executed plan **but for one small detail**, which the detective catches, thus unraveling the plot.

Inherently, this requires the plot antagonist to make a mistake, whether through carelessness, arrogance, or any other (usually negative) trait.

It's perfectly reasonable for people to continue with a plan if there's only a minor inconsistency, if everything else works out in their favor. Not perfect thinking, but guess what, antagonists are humans too.

Comment: Sorry, but please provide some evidence how this oversight could be considered a small mistake. Their plan had a huge flaw.  And noone who was pretending to be injured in the leg would be dumb enough to risk running about on a boat and be seen, unless they had worn a disguise.

Comment: @Whodunit: Until you provide an objective metric for mistake size, we're just going to have to subjectively disagree. You seem to keep constructing your argument based on what you consider to be objectively correct and inevitable, which suggests you may have missed the core of this answer.